# How to remove a Facebook App from Facebook's search results?

Tags: facebook, facebook-application

I have a Facebook app so users can login to my website using their Facebook account, but when you type my website name into Facebook's search (the search box right next to the Facebook logo) the app shows up in the search results. When I click it, it says "Misconfigured App - Sorry, the details for AppName cannot be displayed because the app is misconfigured."

I want to remove my app from Facebook's search results, because it's not meant for users, but I can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not about a website you can control. Should be moved to [Web Applications.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this appears in the listings for everyone else?

Apps I've made appear in my own account's search, but I can't see them from any other account.

Configuring the app properly may be sensible, regardless.

According to this:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/appcenter

```
We encourage all developers to create an App Details page so that 
the app appears in search and can be made eligible for listing in 
the App Center.
```

To me that implies if you don't create a details page, then it won't appear.

Answer (score 0):

[According to StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622911/hide-facebook-app-page-from-search) it is not possible to remove your app from the Facebook search results.

It appears that the best that you can do is set configure the app properly, but make it redirect when a user lands on it.